# passwordless AD domain join

Tags: active-directory, samba4, rodc

I remember back in the olden days of Windows NT you could create "blank" computer accounts so that anyone could join a computer of that name to the domain.

I would like to do the same thing with Active Directory. Specifically:

- create a "blank" computer account for a member or RODC
- join the computer to the domain without interaction

---

The *problem I'm trying to solve* is I have 1,400 samba4 servers that I need to join to the domain as RODCs. I really, really, really don't want to type in the password 1400 times. I want it to be properly automated (puppet/chef/whatever).

Maybe I can solve this using kssh and Kerberos ticket forwarding? Open to ideas.

Comment: What did you [`expect`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect)? Interesting problem, though.

Comment: You... you're going to create 1400 RODCs? Am I understanding that right?

Comment: There are weird behaviors and edge cases that you have to be aware of with 1,400 *Windows* Domain Controllers, nevermind 1,400 samba DCs. If you're asking this question, I'm assuming it's too late to turn back now, but tread very carefully.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My first approach to this would be:

1. Create a new domain user and [give it rights to join computers to the domain](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8aa21820-e22a-4395-a1e9-f40ed705be7a/what-is-the-best-practice-to-give-a-user-permission-to-join-to-the-domain).
2. Embed its username and password into your automation tool (puppet, chef, shell script, whatever).
3. Once all the computers are joined to the domain, you can delete the domain-joining user. If you keep the user, you should change its password or lock the account.